# Task StartNew Action in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, action, task

In C++/CLI is there any way to do the following? (I think answer is no because of no Action support?)

```
public ref class MyClass {
public:
    void TaskMethod();
    void Start();
}

void MyClass::Start() {
    Task^ myTask = Task::Factory->StartNew(??TaskMethod??);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Action is just a delegate, which is fully supported in C++/CLI. (You might be getting it confused with lambdas, which do not have support in C++/CLI.)

Here's the syntax to create a delegate in C++/CLI.

```
Task^ myTask = Task::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Action(this, &MyClass::TaskMethod));
// For non-static methods, specify the object.      ^^^^ 
// Use the C++-style reference to a class method.         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks - that does it.  I had my syntax a bit tangled.

Comment: Just want to add: You can only start tasks with up to one parameter that has to be of the type `Object^`.